MAUI ambiguous routes matched error on PopAsync()
Im getting error when trying to navigate back from pushed page
System.ArgumentException: 'Ambiguous routes matched for: //D_FAULT_TabBar14/IMPL_BooksPage/BooksPage/D_FAULT_ModalReader16 matches found: //D_FAULT_TabBar14/IMPL_BooksPage/BooksPage/D_FAULT_ModalReader16,//D_FAULT_TabBar14/IMPL_BooksPage/BooksPage/D_FAULT_ModalReader16 (Parameter 'uri')'

Im using Shell navigation
<TabBar
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
    Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Background}"
    Shell.TabBarForegroundColor="{DynamicResource HighlightedItem}"
    Shell.TabBarTitleColor="{DynamicResource HighlightedItem}"
    Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor="{DynamicResource DarkerBackground}">
    <ShellContent
    Title="წიგნები"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:BooksPage}"
    Icon="open_book.svg"
    Route="BooksPage" />
......

From BooksPage then i go to Reader like this
ModalReader mr = new ModalReader(book);
await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(mr, true);


from Reader to Bookmarks
BookmarksModal bm = new BookmarksModal(_viewModel.Book?.Title ?? "usaxelo", _viewModel.Sarchevi, (int x) =>
{
    Carousel.ScrollTo(x, animate: false);
});

await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(bm, true);

and when i try to pop that one exception is thrown
           await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync();
what am i do wrong?
registered routes and dependecies but still same error
  public AppShell()
  {
      InitializeComponent();

      Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Authenticator), typeof(Authenticator));
      Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));
      Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(LoginPage), typeof(LoginPage));
      Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(BooksPage), typeof(BooksPage));
      //Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ReaderPage), typeof(ReaderPage));
      //Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ProfilePage), typeof(ProfilePage));
      //Routing.RegisterRoute("books/modalReader", typeof(ModalReader));
      //Routing.RegisterRoute("books/searchPage", typeof(BooksSeachPage));
      //Routing.RegisterRoute("books/reader/bookmarks", typeof(BookmarksModal));
      //Routing.RegisterRoute("books/reader/font", typeof(FontModal));
  }

builder.Services.AddTransient<SessionManagement>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Authenticator>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<LoginPage>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<BooksPage>();
//builder.Services.AddTransient<ReaderPage>();
//builder.Services.AddTransient<ProfilePage>();
//builder.Services.AddTransient<ModalReader>();
//builder.Services.AddTransient<BookmarksModal>();
//builder.Services.AddTransient<FontModal>();



You have already registered the route for BooksPage  in the Shell visual hierarchy
<ShellContent
Title="წიგნები"
....
Route="BooksPage" />

So you don't have to register it again in code behind, just delete this,
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(BooksPage), typeof(BooksPage));

For more info, please refer to Routes

Glad it helps! Happy coding!
